# cmake how to link static library not named with libxxx.a?

Tags: cmake

The correct link command is

```
g++ file1.o file2.o xxx.0 -o target -I./ -I/usr/local/libmylibone/ 
-L./ -L/usr/local/testlib/ ../lib/special_lib/static_lib.a 
-lasn1c++ -lmysqlclient -lnsl -lm -lz -lc -ldl -lpthread -lrt -ljson
```

Please focus on `../lib/special_lib/static_lib.a`, this is a static library and not named with libxxx.a. And I don't know how to write a CMake command to get this correct link command.

I've tried `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(../lib/special_lib/static_lib.a)` and it will be translated to `-l../lib/special_lib/static_lib.a`. I've also tried `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(static_lib)` but got `-lstatic_lib` and failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put the absolute path to your library it should work:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(your_binary /usr/local/lib/static_lib.a)
```

Second option:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(staticlib STATIC IMPORTED)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(staticlib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/lib/static_lib.a)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(your_binary staticlib)
```

The official CMake documentation for importing/exporting targets is [here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets).

Comment: Thanks, but could you give me more info about how to use abs path ? Actually I've tried, but the link command cmake gives me is "g++ files.o  -o binary L/my/absolute/path/to/static_lib  -lstatic_lib", and it doesn't work.

Comment: It should not give you this command. I have linked the official documentation, have a look at it.

Comment: @oyjh Which version of CMake do you use? Is it 2.4 or older? See CMake's [policy CMP0003](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0003.html).

Comment: @Florian I'm using cmake3.3.0. Thanks for your link, it's helpful.

Comment: @Florian I've just tried use abs path in TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES and it works fine. And it will fail to generate the link command when I use relative path.